# MediaWiki: how to create new user using not native authentication PHP

Tags: php, mediawiki, ipb

I have Invision Power Board web-forum. I want to add MediaWiki to this forum.
Found this extension for mediawiki: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:IPBAuth

It's all right, but I need to authenticate users by email, not by user logins.

I've changed some SQL in this extension, but even if I auth users by email they created in mediawiki db with login like email.

How can I check users by email, but create and authenticate them in MediaWiki by login ?

Best regards,

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the code of this extension.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Windows_NTLM_LDAP_Auto_Auth

It automatically creates accounts when users are authenticated based on their network account in a Windows environment.

Comment: I've made hook, based on includes/specials/SpecialUserLogin.php. initUser() function.